# Is it possible to serve two or more static sites from one docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

For example: I have domain1.com - static html and domain2.com static html.

Can I put both in one container created from Nginx image instead of starting different similar container for each one?

Thanks for help! I'm new to docker. Just trying to figure out how to use it right way.

Comment: I already have running docker network with reverse proxy. And can map only one host for one container. But what to do if I want to run two site in one docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you need to configure Nginx to handle virtual host domains.

A tutorial (how to set up virtual hosts on Nginx):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

E.g.

```
docker run -d -i -t \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -v ./domain1.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain1.conf \
  -v ./domain2.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain2.conf \
  -v ./www:/var/www \
  nginx
```

#### domain1.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
  index index.html;
  root /var/www/static1
}
```

#### domain2.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
  index index.html;
  root /var/www/static2
}
```

Comment: How to map this to reverse proxy? I want to have different docker containers with different environment on my server. For example: one container with node environment, one with static sites using Nginx, another one with sites based on Wordpress

Comment: As for now I have reverse proxy network container. When I starting new container I just passing virtual host through the variable. Then start docker-compose exposing it to appropriate port 443 (SSL). And reverse proxy container do the stuff - issuing cert. Then in dns config add domain A record mapping to my ip.